# using radio value in JS function to retrieve JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms

previously I received great solutions to this little project i'm doing.
now I'm looking to scale it some more but i need to get over this hurdle.
working site: http://oceanmeasure.info

previous posts were:

[HTML select value passed into Javascript var (then used to fetch JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545522/html-select-value-passed-into-javascript-var-then-used-to-fetch-json)

[retrieve JSON data based on user selection/prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534814/retrieve-json-data-based-on-user-selection-prompt)

current not working code:
https://jsfiddle.net/zt074c01/

the main process i am wanting to do currently is learn how to switch out the drop down box for ocean value to radio buttons instead because it is only 2 options. Above i added a fiddle link but below i will add just the main.js file because thats where i think the error is.

```
    (function(){
//------Set variables

var userOcean = getRadioVal( document.getElementById('dataForm'), 'oceanVal' );
var userFish  = document.getElementById("fishVal");
var buttonInfo  = document.getElementById("getInfo");
var output  = document.getElementById("oceanOutput");
var btnLicenseY = document.getElementById('licenseYes');
var btnLicenseN = document.getElementById('licenseNo');
var licenseOutput  = document.getElementById("licenseOutput");

//------Start function on click
buttonInfo.addEventListener('click', function() {
var ocean = userOcean.options[userOcean.checked].value;
var kind = userFish.options[userFish.selectedIndex].value;
var fishImg = jsonObject.ocean_measure[ocean]['fish'][kind].image;
output.innerHTML = "<h2>Fish On!</h2><div id=\"fishInfo\">"+
    "<img src='" +fishImg+ "' />" +
    "<p>fish:  "+jsonObject.ocean_measure[ocean]['fish'][kind].name+"</p>"+
    "<p>length:  "+jsonObject.ocean_measure[ocean]['fish'][kind].length+"</p>"+
    "<p>closed:  "+jsonObject.ocean_measure[ocean]['fish'][kind].closed+"</p>"+
    "<p>limit:  "+jsonObject.ocean_measure[ocean]['fish'][kind].limit+"</p>"+
    "<p>remarks:  "+jsonObject.ocean_measure[ocean]['fish'][kind].remarks+"</p>";
    console.log(
    "<img src='" +fishImg+ "' />" +
    "\n\nfish:  "+jsonObject.ocean_measure[ocean]['fish'][kind].name+
    "\n\nlength:  "+jsonObject.ocean_measure[ocean]['fish'][kind].length+
    "\n\nclosed:  "+jsonObject.ocean_measure[ocean]['fish'][kind].closed+
    "\n\nlimit:  "+jsonObject.ocean_measure[ocean]['fish'][kind].limit+
    "\n\nremarks:  "+jsonObject.ocean_measure[ocean]['fish'][kind].remarks+
"</div>"
);
});
//------end info function
//------start license function

btnLicenseY.addEventListener('click', function(){
licenseOutput.innerHTML = "<h3>Lets Fish!</h3>"+ "<p>You're all set go ahead and select which coast you'll be fishing, and your target species.</p>"
});
//------end yes license function
btnLicenseN.addEventListener('click', function(){
licenseOutput.innerHTML = "<h3>Uh Oh!</h3>"+ "<p>Let's make sure you get that taken care of before you hit the open waters, remember some piers &amp charters require you to pay for access and a one day fishing license may be included in that access, be sure to call and find out ahead of time.</p>"+
"<h4>Get my License</h4>"+"<p>If you'd rather not risk it go ahead and visit <a href=http://myfwc.com/license/recreational/saltwater-fishing/ target=_blank>Here</a> to purchase the best license for you!</p>"
});
//------end no license function

//--------RADIO Function

function getRadioVal(form, name) {
    var val;
    // get list of radio buttons with specified name
    var radios = form.elements[name];

    // loop through list of radio buttons
    for (var i=0, len=radios.length; i<len; i++) {
        if ( radios[i].checked ) { // radio checked?
            val = radios[i].value; // if so, hold its value in val
            break; // and break out of for loop
        }
    }
    return val; // return value of checked radio or undefined if none checked
}


})();
```

Comment: I'd prefer vanilla JS over jQuery, but if I am unable to learn a solution I will work with jQuery until I can work out the vJS later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="radioElement" id="radio1" value="option-a" checked>
<input type="radio" name="radioElement" id="radio2" value="opption-b">
```

JS

```
$('input[name="radioElement"].checked').val();
```