# Trying to extract output from a json file based on user selection in a drop-down-menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, drop-down-menu

I am trying to present a user with a drop-down-list and give an output based on user's selection. The drop-down-list options are populated via a json file and I want the output to come from the json (based on the selection of course).

This is the json:

```
{
  "101":  {"title":"a title", 
           "shelf":"shelf 1",
           "floor":"1",
           "udcStartAt":"123.3",
           "udcEndAt":"133.29"},
  "102":  {"title":"b title", 
           "shelf":"shelf 2",
           "floor":"1",
           "udcStartAt":"133.3",
           "udcEndAt":"134.69"},
  "103":  {"title":"c title", 
           "shelf":"shelf 3",
           "floor":"1",
           "udcStartAt":"134.7",
           "udcEndAt":"136.59"}
}
```

This is my current javascript:

```
//this one gets the json and sends it to the jsonToDdl(data) function

function simpleJsonShow(){
  $.getJSON("test.json", jsonToDdl);
}

//this one populate the drop-down-list

function jsonToDdl(data){
  for (sNumber in data){
    $("#selectNumberTwo").append("<option>" + sNumber + "</\option>");
    }
}
```

I want the output to be the nested values for each option, for example - when 101 is selected, the output should be: 1 , 123.3 , 133.29.

I have looked for solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534814/retrieve-json-data-based-on-user-selection-prompt) but I did not fully understand the method presented there.

Comment: Try this, `$.each(your_json, function (key, data) {console.log(key);$.each(data,function (index, data) {console.log('index', data);})})`

Comment: Thanks you! I don't know where exactly I need to add your code (I'm only beginning to understand JavaScript). I tried several options and in all the cases got from chrome debugger the following error: "jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in test.json".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

```
function showNestedOutput(){
$.getJSON("data\\topicToShelf.json", showNestedResult);  /*get json file and pass to showNestedResult()*/
function showNestedResult(data){
    var selection = $("#selectTopic option:selected").text(); // the var 'selection' stores user's selection text
    var nestedResult = "your result" + data[selection].title + " located: " + data[selection].shelf + " floor: " + data[selection].floor;
    $("#outputTopics").html(nestedResult);
    }

}
```